# why this compile, but doesnt change the seticon

Tags: java, swing, button

im just studying java but..

why its not changing? i can change the icon using the set icon if i put it in the action listener of the button :|

MAIN CLASS

```
package tstando;

public class executor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Tela inicia = new Tela();
        inicia.run();
    }
}
```

THE CLASS of the GUI(tela)

```
package tstando;    

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;    
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;    

public class Tela extends JFrame {    

    public JLabel lblImage = new JLabel("New label");

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public JPanel contentPane;

            public void run() {
                try {
                    Tela frame = new Tela();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    public Tela() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);            
        lblImage.setBounds(71, 31, 277, 150);
        contentPane.add(lblImage);          
        lblImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Chrysanthemum.jpg"));         
        JButton btnAlteraImagem = new JButton("Altera Imagem");
        btnAlteraImagem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            metodos met = new metodos();    
            //lblImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg"));
            }               
        });
        btnAlteraImagem.setBounds(148, 213, 182, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnAlteraImagem);
    }
}
```

and the class of the method

```
package tstando;

import java.io.IOException;    
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;    

public class metodos {

Tela altera = new Tela();
String link = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg";

    public void alterajlabel() throws IOException {
        altera.lblImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(link));       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you never call `alterajlabel`, second of all, the instance of `Tela` in your `alterajlabel` of your `metodos` class isn't the same instance that is on the screen.  You just simply create another copy of it and modified it.

Instead, you should pass a reference of `Tela` to `metodos` when you create it, that way `metodos` can deal with the instance that is on the screen

You will need to change your `metodos` class to look more like...

```
public class metodos {
    Tela tela;
    String link = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg";

    public metods(Tela tela) {
        this.tela = tela;
    }

    public void alterajlabel() throws IOException {
        tela.lblImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(link));
    }
}
```

You would then need to modify the `ActionListener` of your `btnAlteraImagem` to more like...

```
btnAlteraImagem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        metodos met = new metodos(Tela.this);
        try {
            met.alterajlabel();
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

You could also do...

```
public class metodos {

    String link = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg";
    public void alterajlabel(Tela tela) throws IOException {
        tela.lblImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(link));
    }
}
```

And call it like...

```
btnAlteraImagem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        metodos met = new metodos();
        try {
            met.alterajlabel(Tela.this);
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Which is, probably a slightly better approach.

To my mind however, it would be better to do something like...

```
public class metodos {

    String link = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg";
    public void alterajlabel(JLabel label) throws IOException {
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(link));
    }
}
```

Which you would call like...

```
btnAlteraImagem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        metodos met = new metodos();
        try {
            met.alterajlabel(lblImage);
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Which means you are not exposing the `Tela` unnecessarily

You may want to look over [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) and [Learning the Java Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) for some more details

Also, while I know that might seem confusion, I would strongly recommend that you take the time to learn how to [use layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Comment: reading, to understand, i will answer in some minutes!! thx the answer!!

Comment: *"worked like a charm*" - Opps, must have done something wrong ;) - Nice to know it helped